# is interactivePopTransition to handle gesture to pop the view controller like Instagram not supporting RTL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, right-to-left

I'm using "interactivePopTransition" to make user move between view controllers by pan gesture , It's work fine with me when my app direction is LTR but I'm going to use it in another direction RTL but it still pop the view from left to right , I tried many times with different codes with no result and no reference from apple if it support the direction .

**I tried this line of code in ViewDidLoad with same result :**

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
```

And also this solution that I was followed :

http://ioscake.com/navigation-pop-view-when-swipe-right-like-instagram-iphone-app-how-i-achieve-this.html

**I used the Objective-c section :**

```
CustomPopTransition.h 
CustomPopTransition.m  
SecondViewController.h  
SecondViewController.m
```

Comment: Without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can't help you.

Comment: I edit the question , Please check .

Comment: I found something actually it works fine in LTR , But the problem cause when I changed the app. language to RTL it's not work until I restart the app then it works in the RTL direction , So may the cause of the problem is changing language inside the app. Still solving the issue .